# Custom database connection not working in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this class that would establish a connection to the MySQL database in php. But there seems to be something wrong with it, and clearly I am making a mistake.

This is the class:

```
class dbConnection {

    public $CONN;

    public function __construct() {
        $dbservername = "localhost";
        $dbusername = "test";
        $dbpassword = "pass";
        $dbname = "dbtest";

        // Create connection
        $this->CONN = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($this->CONN->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $CONN->connect_error);
        }
        return $this->CONN;
    }

    public function close() {
        $this->CONN->close();
    }
}
```

This is calling the class to perform an `INSERT`:

```
$conn = new dbConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (stuff1, stuff2, stuff3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $val1, $val2, $val3);

// set parameters and execute
$val1 = "val1";
$val2 = "foo";
$val3 = "bar";
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The error showing is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method dbConnection::prepare() in /var/www/index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/index.php on line 7
```

This works if I set up a function inside the class and call it instead of the constructor, but I would like to have it done with the constructor itself.
How do I establish this?

Comment: new Class() returns the class object and not the return value

Comment: Is there a way that I can retrieve the return value?

Comment: Alright I got it that constructors don't return any value. But can I make it something like `$conn= new mysqli();` with my class?

Comment: Before you get too deep down this rabbit hole you'll want to evaluate using an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/). Writing your own is always going to be harder and less productive than using an existing, field tested solution.

Comment: Try `mysqli_connect()` for connection.

Comment: @IlyasDattoo you do understand that I am using the OOP version of mysqli, right?

Comment: Yes @CoderDudeTwodee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `prepare` method for the `dbConnection` class:

```
public function prepare($query) {
    return $this->CONN->prepare($query);
}
```

and your current code would work. Tested it on my machine and it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Applying custom and systemfunctions to the same object is not possible so you have to mirror the systemfunctions on your custom object:

```
class connect{
public $CONN;
function __construct(){
$this->CONN=new mysqli();
}
function prepare($statement){
     $this->CONN->prepare($statement);
 }
```

Comment: I don't know if you know this, but my code is in php.

Comment: @CoderDude Twodee: I know but because i usually code in javascript, i sometimes use a wrong syntax

Comment: @CoderDude Twodee : Sorry, i thought creating an object with {} was possible :( . ive updated my answrr